# python if condition and "and"

Tags: python

```
 >>> def foo(a):
        print "called the function"
        if(a==1):
            return 1
        else:
            return None
>>> a=1

>>> if(foo(a) != None and foo(a) ==1):
    print "asdf"

called the function
called the function
asdf
```

Hi.
  how can i avoid calling the function twice without using an extra variable.

Comment: you can save the result of `foo(a)` into a variable. Then check the variable value in `if()` clause.

Comment: Exactly, for the second condition to be `True`, the first has to be. Also note that brackets around the condition are considered bad form in Python. `if(a==1):` should just be `if a==1:`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can chain the comparisons like this

```
if None != foo(a) == 1:
```

This works like

```
if (None != foo(a)) and (foo(a) == 1):
```

except that it only evaluates foo(a) once.

Comment: You can chain **equality** comparisons? Well, look at that!

Comment: @uʍop ǝpısdn, yep it works the same (with an implicit `and`) as the other comparisons in your answer

Comment: While this is a good _general_ answer, the first check is still redundant in the given case.

Comment: @Lattyware, I assume the given case was just a poor example. NPE has that covered anyway

Comment: @gnibbler The OP's comment on NPE's answer says that *'my actual problem is similar to this'*. And yeah, I'm just making the point that often logical wrangling can be avoided by simplifying the logic beforehand.

Comment: i gave poor example but was actually looking for this solution. i didn't knew we can chain that way.

Answer (score 7):

> how can i avoid calling the function twice without using an extra variable.

Here, you can simply replace

```
if(foo(a) != None and foo(a) ==1):
```

with

```
if foo(a) == 1:
```

The `foo(a) != None` is redundant: if `foo(a) == 1`, it is guaranteed to not be `None`.

Comment: Maybe the posted code is not the real code but just an example. 
if(foo(a) != None and foo(a) ==1): 
sounds as a better solution

Comment: @jimifiki If the function has side effects, that could cause problems. Besides, this is the best answer to the asked question. If the OP has over-simplified it, then he needs to ask a new question.

Comment: This is not answering the question. I agree with @jimifiki. And no it's not the best, see below

Comment: my bad i didn't knew that. this is the answer i need . my actual problem is similar to this. this works for me.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn It answers the question - this in no way deserves a -1, as it is correct. It might not be as _general_ a solution, but it's the best solution for the given problem.

Comment: he deleted his answer . but that solution was best .

Answer (score 1):

The following statement

```
if foo(a) == 1:
```

will deal with both conditions.

Answer (score 1):

if foo(a)==1 ,then foo(a) will not be None,

so simplify your code to:

```
if foo(a):
    print('asdf')
```

Comment: Assuming that he means "Any value that evaluates to true" is a bit dodgy, I think.

Comment: i don't think there is a difference between if foo(a) and if foo(a)== 1 ,here.